# XML results are overridden when multiple suites are executed

Tags: testing, automated-tests, testng, integration-testing, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm running my TestNG tests Programatically. I'm Injecting multiple suites and executing. But when I execute the following, testng-results.xml doesn't contain all the results from each suite. I only get results of the last suite. Has anyone faced the same issue before?

```
            TestNG tng = new TestNG();
            List<XmlSuite> suites = new ArrayList<>();

            for (Deployment deployment : deploymentList) {

            tcList = tlsite.getTestCaseClassList();

                XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();
                suite.setName(deployment.getName());
                XmlTest test = new XmlTest(suite);
                test.setName("AutomationTests");
                List<XmlClass> classes = new ArrayList<>();

                for (Object className : tcList){
                    try {
                        classes.add(new XmlClass((String) className));
                    } catch (TestNGException e){
                        log.error("Error occurred while adding the class : " +e.toString());
                    }
                }
                test.setXmlClasses(classes) ;
                suites.add(suite);
            }
            tng.setXmlSuites(suites);
            tng.setOutputDirectory("my-out"); 
            tng.run();
```

Update : If I run this in the following way it works. But I want o dynamically generate the suite. What am I doing wrong?

```
            TestNG testng = new TestNG();
            List<String> suites = new ArrayList<>();
            suites.add("../src/test/resources/testng.xml"); 
            testng.setTestSuites(suites);
            testng.run();
```

testng.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="suite of suites">
    <suite-files>
        <suite-file path="testng_pattern1.xml" />
        <suite-file path="testng_pattern2.xml" />
    </suite-files>
</suite>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have provided example which is working as you are expecting, I hope, see [GitHub](https://github.com/RocketRaccoon/TestNG-Examples/blob/master/src/test/java/SuiteOfSuites.java). You need to set parent suite for your suites using `childSuite.setParentSuite(parentSuite)` for all your nested suites.

Comment: I want the results in a single file.

Comment: You mean single file or single report?

Comment: I need all the results in a single testng-result.xml. As i mentioned when I use the second method it works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.